# How to trigger radio button's event handler programmatically?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, event-handling, radio-button

please have a look at the following code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace calc
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        //code removed

        public Form1()
        {

            InitializeComponent();
            calculator = new Calculator();

            maleRadio.PerformClick();
            englishRadio.PerformClick();
        }


/*code removed*/

        //Action Listener for Female Radio button
        private void femaleRadio_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //code removed
        }

        //Action Listener for English Radio button
        private void englishRadio_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //code removed
        }



    }
}
```

I am somewhat new to c#. what I want to do here is to trigger the `event handlers` of radio buttons inside the constructor programatically. The way I followed `maleRadio.PerformClick();`do nothing. how can I call the event handlers inside the constructor programmertically ?

Comment: Does radio_checkChanged not working?

Comment: hm, you are doing `PerformClick` but want to handle `CheckedChanged`. Eren Ersönmez answer should work :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can call the event handlers like any other method:

```
public Form1()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   calculator = new Calculator();

   maleRadio_CheckedChanged(maleRadio, null);
   englishRadio_CheckedChanged(englishRadio, null);
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is what the OP wants. +1 :)

Comment: ahh great! thanks a lot! however, i can see the radio buttons are not visible as selected, even though they performed the event handler. how can i make it visible as they are clicked?

Comment: @Knight have you got your last question figured out (since you've marked this as the answer)?  I basically directly answered your question of "how do I trigger the event handler", however, if you want to actually set the checked state of the radio button then you need to do 'maleRadio.Checked = true;' instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can just call the function `femaleRadio_CheckedChanged` on your constructor. Or you can set the value of the selected index of the radiobutton to trigger the event:

```
femaleRadio_CheckedChanged(null, null);
or
femaleRadio.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just call the method:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        radioButton1.CheckedChanged += radioButton1_CheckedChanged;

        //Triggering the handlers programmatically
        radioButton1_CheckedChanged(null, null);
        radioButton2_CheckedChanged(null, null);
    }

    //this handler is manually added in the constructor
    void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Test event 1");
    }

    //This handler is auto-generated by designer, after adding the event in the designer
    private void radioButton2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Test event 2");
    }
}
```

Output is going to be:

Test event 1
Test event 2
Test event 1

because after the constructor has finished, radiobutton1 will be selected as default.